# Problem with Login using Facebook

Tags: facebook, login, slideshare

I'm trying to login to SlideShare using Facebook Login and all I get is a popup window pointing to this address:

```
https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#cb=f3ae2149bc&origin=https://www.slideshare.net/f2b476d02c&relation=opener&transport=postmessage&frame=f37401c08c&result={"perms":"email","selected_profiles":550961403,"session":"{\"session_key\":\"2.AQAVh-B5Kc-xWLBJ.3600.1315483200.1-550961403\",\"uid\":\"550961403\",\"expires\":1315483200,\"secret\":\"owDBvV3kXW2gQE6C52KQ1g__\",\"base_domain\":\"slideshare.net\",\"access_token\":\"2490221586|2.AQAVh-B5Kc-xWLBJ.3600.1315483200.1-550961403|SfxMzagpRUqcvZfrHfsfv2fbtr0\",\"sig\":\"e9d9d04be721c0532c87d74d12cc832c\"}"}
```

The login never takes place.

Any help?

Comment: This no longer occurs. I am able to login to Facebook. This was most likely a bug.